# typeof Float32Array With Ternary Operator Syntax

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to understand the code on http://matthew.wagerfield.com/flat-surface-shader/ and one of the first lines is confusing me:

```
FSS.Array = typeof Float32Array === 'function' ? Float32Array : Array;
```

What does this line above do?

I believe the ?: at the end is saying "if something then equals Float32Array, else equals Array".  But I don't understand how the typeof Float32Array === 'function' works.  Is it saying if typeof Float32Array is exactly equal to the string 'function'?  That doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is checking for browser support of the javascript function Float32Array

the ternary expression equates to:

```
if (typeof Float32Array == "function") {
    FSS.Array = Float32Array;
} else {
    FSS.Array = Array;
}
```

typeof simply returns the type of the variable, in this case the variable is "Float32Array"

Here are the docs on typeof:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof

Here are some other examples from the docs:

```
// Numbers
typeof 37 === 'number';
typeof 3.14 === 'number';
typeof Math.LN2 === 'number';
typeof Infinity === 'number';
typeof NaN === 'number'; // Despite being "Not-A-Number"
typeof Number(1) === 'number'; // but never use this form!


// Strings
typeof "" === 'string';
typeof "bla" === 'string';
typeof (typeof 1) === 'string'; // typeof always return a string
typeof String("abc") === 'string'; // but never use this form!


// Booleans
typeof true === 'boolean';
typeof false === 'boolean';
typeof Boolean(true) === 'boolean'; // but never use this form!


// Symbols
typeof Symbol() === 'symbol'
typeof Symbol('foo') === 'symbol'
typeof Symbol.iterator === 'symbol'


// Undefined
typeof undefined === 'undefined';
typeof blabla === 'undefined'; // an undefined variable


// Objects
typeof {a:1} === 'object';

// use <a href="/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray" title="/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray">Array.isArray</a> or Object.prototype.toString.call
// to differentiate regular objects from arrays
typeof [1, 2, 4] === 'object';

typeof new Date() === 'object';


// The following is confusing. Don't use!
typeof new Boolean(true) === 'object'; 
typeof new Number(1) === 'object'; 
typeof new String("abc") === 'object';


// Functions
typeof function(){} === 'function';
typeof Math.sin === 'function';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (typeof Float32Array === 'function')
    FSS.Array = Float32Array
else
    FSS.Array = Array
```

[Ternary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

[Operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence)

```
          4 1                   2              3              3 
          V V                   V              V              V
FSS.Array = typeof Float32Array === 'function' ? Float32Array : Array;
```

About type [Float32Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Float32Array)

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of feature detection with a fallback.  Float32Array is a kind of typed arrays.

Typed arrays are more efficient than normal arrays because they allow the JS engine to store large quantities of numbers in smaller formats.  All numbers in JavaScript are 64 bit floating point numbers, so they can use half of the memory to store a Float32Array, and make optimizations around math with these numbers.

Because typed arrays are a subset of arrays (except for clamped typed arrays), you can use an array when typed arrays aren't available (older browsers).

It can be read as "If Float32Array exists and is a function, store that in FSS.Array, otherwise store Array in FSS.Array."

If you then do `new FSS.Array(3000)` you'll either get a Float32Array with 3000 slots, or an array with 3000 initial slots.